# How do I loop through MySQL results in sections, with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping someone can help me on this...

Here's my query:

```
$query_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC LIMIT 30") or die(mysql_error());
$row_articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_articles);
```

What I would like to do is show all 30 results, but I want it to be like this:

```
// Show article #1

// Then loop through articles 2-7

// Then show article #8

// Then loop through articles 9-30
```

The reason is because I have different formatting for each set listed above. I could easily do separate queries, but it's not ideal, plus it would screw up my pagination afterwards.

So how would I do these loops with that one query? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**///// UPDATE /////**

Ok this is what I have now and it gives me exactly what I want BUT it also shows rows 31-42 (which don't even exist right now in my DB):

```
$query_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC LIMIT 32") or die(mysql_error());
$row_articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_articles);

$shown_articles = array(1, 8);
$article_index = 1;
foreach ($row_articles as $article) {
do {
    if (in_array($article_index, $shown_articles)) { 

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo '</p>';

    } else {

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo '</p>';

    }
    $article_index++;
} while($row_articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_articles));
}
```

Any idea as to why it's showing extras rows? Also, if I use mysql_fetch_array, it goes up to row 55.

**///// UPDATE /////**

Here's my final code if anyone else needs it. I also added another conditional because I also wanted to separate the 9-30 rows.

```
$query_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC LIMIT 32") or die(mysql_error());

$shown_articles = array(1, 8);
$article_range = range(9, 30);
$article_index = 1;

while($row_articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_articles)) {
    if (in_array($article_index, $shown_articles)) { 

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo '</p>';

    } elseif (in_array($article_index, $article_range)) { 

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo ' - 9-30</p>';

    } else {

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo ' - 2-7</p>';

    }
    $article_index++;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean loop through 2-7 and 9-30? Do you want to display a title or anything about them or just skip them altogether and only display 1 and 8?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you can avoid it, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I want to display the title, for example. So, $row_articles['title'] and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You first create an iterator based on your result:

```
$rows = new ArrayIterator($row_articles);
```

Then you want to prevent that iterator to rewind:

```
$articles = new NoRewindIterator($rows);
```

This helps you to create sub-iterators (e.g. for your listing) to not rewind but to continue.

Then you can operate on it like you see fit:

```
foreach ($articles as $i => $article)
{
    switch ($i)
    {
        case 1:
            article_display($article);
            article_list(new LimitIterator($articles, 0, 6));
            break;

        case 8:
            article_display($article);
            article_list(new LimitIterator($articles, 0, 21));
            break;

        default:
            throw new Excpetion(sprintf("Unexpected i: %d", $i));
    }
}
```

Note: It might be that `$i` is zero based, then you need to change the hardcoded numbers in the `case` statements as I have written it 1 based. But I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to achieve this:

```
$query_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC LIMIT 30") or die(mysql_error());
$row_articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_articles);

$i=0;
foreach($row_articles as $article) {
  if($i % 8 == 0) {
    // do stuff for row 0, 8 ..
  }
  else {
    // do stuff for other rows
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: But article 16 is between 9 and 30, and it shouldn't be shown.

Comment: @WaleedKhan He also said `Then loop through articles 9-30` , but I'm pretty sure he does want to show articles matching a multiple of 8, with the exception of the first one.

Comment: I'm not sure of this one, modulo operator is new to me. Yes, I want to have the first article, then loop 2-7, then show #8, then 9-30.

Comment: @Ironank Are you _sure_ you dont mean to loop through 9-31 and show number 32? (30 is not a multiple of 8). To do this, you really need to pick a multiple , or have a pre-defined array of which articles should be displayed up to (however many could be returned) :) Your question starts with 'show #1', so I don't think I'm off by one here.

Comment: Ya it could be 28 or 32, whatever, I just picked 30.

Answer (score 0):

```
$shown_articles = array(1, 8);
$article_index = 1;
foreach ($row_article as $article) {
    if (in_array($article_index, $shown_articles)) { 
        // Show article
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
    $article_index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You (and all the other answers) are confused about what `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns. It doesn't return an array with all the rows, it returns just one row. You normally shouldn't be iterating through this array, you just access the specific columns you want.

I don't understand your `if` statement, though, since it does the same thing in both branches. I guess the real application does different things, I've just inserted placeholders.

```
$query_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC LIMIT 32") or die(mysql_error());

$shown_articles = array(1, 8);
$article_index = 1;
while ($row_articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_articles)) {
    if (in_array($article_index, $shown_articles)) { 

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo '<br>Stuff for articles in $shown_articles';
        echo '</p>';

    } else {

        echo '<p>'.$article_index.' ';
        echo $row_articles['title'];
        echo '<br>Stuff for articles NOT in $shown_articles';
        echo '</p>';

    }
    $article_index++;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was just about to post this solution as I realized that I didn't need the foreach. Works great just like that with the while loop. The if (in_array($article_index, $shown_articles)) I used from Waleed's example above. Would there be a better solution than that?

Comment: The if(in_array(...)) seems fine to me. It's just that you weren't doing anything different based on it.